# How to implement an auto-complete for a text editor written in java?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtextpane

I'm trying to create a text editor like program for coding in mips assembly using java , the point i got mixed up alittle was the part i was trying to provide a Control-Space feature like that of eclipse's.For example when the user enters `add $s1` , then presses ctrl+Space , i would replace this string:`"add $s1 , $s2 , $s3"`  with what he has typed! ( that's an example .. i know add can be of immediate type instructions :D ), I'm using a hashmap to bind key strokes to what will actually happen in my JTextPane , sth like :

```
InputMap inputMap = textPane.getInputMap();
KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('some keys') ;
inputMap.put(key, 'some action') ;
```

well the problem is , when i want to implement Ctrl+Space for my program , i am using this :

```
key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(Event.CTRL_MASK , KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) ;
inputMap.put(key, DefaultEditorKit.insertContentAction);
```

but where can I select , what string should be inserted instead of the already typed part of the pattern ? other words , where does the insertContentAction bring it strings from ? how can i define what String should be replaced ? or even is there any other better ways for replacing , when Ctrl+Space has been pressed ?
(what im asking for is a way to insert the string pattern into a jTextPane , not the algorithm to implement the pattern matching )
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use `insertContentAction`. You have to link the shortcut to your own [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) subclass that inserts the completion into the document.

Comment: @Inerdial yea i guess that's the way to do it , but can u bring an example of linking Actions to shortcuts ?

Comment: The Swing tutorial has a section on key bindings: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Answer (score 1):

You can [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument%28%29) the [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) of the text pane to make tightly controlled changes such as these. The `Document` also has some useful events of its own that you can listen for.