# Java Text Editor auto-complete and indenting logic

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, netbeans-7

Well, I'm new in Java. I'm developing a text editor. Actually, I have two questions.

1. How can I add auto complete "{}". Which class should i use? Should I use BufferedReader or BufferedWriter or anythings else?
2. What is the logic behind auto indenting?

I searched in google over 100 times. Nothing comes up!

Comment: What do you mean by "auto complete {}", and why would it use a reader/writer?

Comment: Take a look that this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032969/how-to-implement-an-auto-complete-for-a-text-editor-written-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Your questions don't make sense.  Since you're new to Java, you should try and get a Windows Notepad clone working before you tackle more complex editor behaviors.

Auto-complete and auto-indenting require that the editor know what type of text is being edited.

To take one example, English text auto-completing would probably use a list of the uncommon English words used before in the editor.  Auto-indenting would automatically indent the cursor one tab at the start of a paragraph.

The rules for auto-complete and auto-indenting would be different for Java code.  The editor would have to recognize Java syntax and maintain a list of Java methods.

The mechanics of auto-complete are matching what the user is typing with a list of words (for the first example) or Java methods (for the second example).  Since more than one word or method is likely to match, you display a list, and let the user choose one if so desired.

Answer (score 2):

It may be helpful if you described what your intentions are behind creating this text editor.

There is already a text editor that supports syntax highlighting for multiple languages called JSyntaxPane.

See http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/